# laser_scan_matcher with hydro

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, gmapping, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to run laser_scan_matcher with hydro?  I am wanting to run my laser with gmapping with out  odometry.  Is there another way to do it?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195323/laser_scan_matcher-with-hydro/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the source version of the laser_scan_matcher supports catkin, and should work on Hydro: https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on 2014-11-20**:
Even i have to use laser scan matcher package how to make use of it?when i do catkin_make i get error of csm/csm_all.h not found,i have downloaded csm.h file still i have this error .along with this .h file should i do some other modifications in any file?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-20**:
You should probably ask a new question and copy and paste the exact command and the error message you're getting.